# Setting value of a text using name of another checkbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two object in my screen one check box and a text box.

check box name and id is '105'

I have taken its name as

```
var chk_name = document.getElementsByName('105');
```

text box name is dynamically created and is 'text_105'.

I tried below code to set the value of text box. Which is not working

```
$('#text_'+chk_name[0].name).val(chk_name[0].name);
```

expect value of textbox text_105 as 105

Comment: Variable contain checkbox is `chk_name` but you used `cboxes` in `.val()`

Comment: @Mohammad it was typo

Comment: The code you've shown works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/b1qvmLdf/. Ensure you're running it at the correct point in the page lifecycle

Comment: @Rory Thanks its resolved

Answer (score 0):

> text box name is dynamically created and is 'text_105'.

It seems you need `name` but you are trying to  access the dom using id selector`$('#text_'+chk_name[0].name)`

```js
var chk_name = document.getElementsByName('106');


$('input[name=text_' + chk_name[0].name + ']').val(chk_name[0].name);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' name='106' id='105'>
<input type='text' name='text_106'>
```